# How call render in component, after get data in redux-saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I am trying get new data from redux saga, but i cant get it. New date dont refresh in my component, but in redux they are updated.

sagas.js

```
function* getApiData(action) {
  try {
    // do api call
    const data = yield call(fetchData);
    yield put(receiveApiData(data));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

component

```
  render() {
    const  results  = this.props.data;
    if (results.lenght) { // I'm trying to check for storage length, but this does not work
      return (
        results.map((item, index) => {
          <div key={index}>
          <h1>
            {item.dstOffset}
          </h1>
          <h1>
            {item.rawOffset}
          </h1>
          <h1>
            {item.timeZoneId}
          </h1>
        </div>} )
      )
   }
   else {
     return (
       <div>loading</div>
     )
   }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ data: state.data });
```

Comment: your component need to be connected to redux, make sure you are not missing that

Comment: component  connected to redux, trouble is not this

Comment: You've misspelled `length` as `lenght` - is that the only issue perhaps? Can you share the reducer that handles the `recieveApiData` action and how it's hooked up to your store? Are you sure it is updating the top-level `data` key directly?